# PLC : Connecting AB Micrologix 1200 on Ethernet Network for Point Discovery

Tags: plc

I am new to PLC Programming.

I am looking to connect AB Micrologix 1200 on Ethernet Network for Point Discovery through Software.

Port 0 is connected to Preprogrammed HMI and operating on Modbus RTU.

I want to use 1761-NET-AIC Card for this purpose, But I am confused how I should connect PLC with this card when already HMI is connected to PLC on Port 0.

The ultimate goal is to acquire real time data and store in DB.

I plan to use Python/C# to acquire the data once I am clear on hardware connecting.

Please Guide.